# Revisiting: Plotting Population Regression Function with pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want the make the following population regression function after some modifications with `pgfplot` (response from previous question [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HpUr.png)).

[image]

**Required Modifications**

1. Draw small circle at each normal distributions mean.
2. Draw a line that passes through the means.
3. Join means with `xticklabs` and `yticklabs`.

Here is my MWE. Thanks for any help.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ % Define Normal Probability Function
declare function={
            normal(\x,\m,\s) = 1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(\x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
        }
       ]

\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (6,6);

\begin{axis}[
    no markers,
    domain=-3.2:3.2,
    samples=100,
    axis lines=left,
    enlarge x limits=true,
    enlarge y limits=true,
    xtick={0,0.5,1},
    ytick={0,0.5,1},
    xticklabels={$X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$},
    yticklabels={$Y_1$, $Y_2$, $Y_3$},
    xlabel=$X$, xlabel style={at=(xticklabel cs:1), anchor=south},
    ylabel=$Y$, ylabel style={at=(yticklabel cs:1), rotate=-90, anchor=west},
  ]


\addplot [samples=2, domain=0:1.4] {2.5+4*x};
\addplot[cyan!50!black, thick, domain=0:6] ({normal(x, 3, 1)+0.0},x);
\addplot[cyan!50!black, thick, domain=2:8] ({normal(x, 5, 1)+0.5},x);
\addplot[cyan!50!black, thick, domain=4:10] ({normal(x, 7, 1)+1},x);

\draw (0, 0) --(5, 16) -- (0, 16);
\draw[fill] (5, 16) circle [radius=2.0pt];

\node[above right] (5,15) {$\mathbf{E}\left(Y|X_{i}\right)=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}X$};

\node[above right] (15,25) {Distribution of \\$Y$ values \\given $X=x_3$};

\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

My node placement is not correct.

**Edited**

Following @Qrrbrbirlbel comment, I have partial solution:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ % Define Normal Probability Function
declare function={
            normal(\x,\m,\s) = 1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(\x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
        }
       ]

\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (6,6);

\begin{axis}[
    no markers,
    domain=-3.2:3.2,
    samples=100,
    axis lines=left,
    enlarge x limits=true,
    enlarge y limits=true,
    xtick={0, 0.5, 1},
    ytick={3, 5, 7},
    xticklabels={$X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$},
    yticklabels={$Y_1$, $Y_2$, $Y_3$},
    xlabel=$X$, xlabel style={at=(xticklabel cs:1), anchor=south},
    ylabel=$Y$, ylabel style={at=(yticklabel cs:1), rotate=-90, anchor=west},
  ]


\addplot[cyan!50!black, thick, domain=0:6] ({normal(x, 3, 1)+0.0},x);
\addplot[cyan!50!black, thick, domain=2:8] ({normal(x, 5, 1)+0.5},x);
\addplot[cyan!50!black, thick, domain=4:10] ({normal(x, 7, 1)+1},x);

\draw[dashed] (axis cs: 0, -1) -- (axis cs: 0, 3);
\draw[dashed] (axis cs: -1, 3) -- (axis cs: 0, 3);
\draw[fill] (axis cs: 0.0, 3) circle [radius=2.0pt];

\draw[dashed] (axis cs: 0.5, -1) -- (axis cs: 0.5, 5);
\draw[dashed] (axis cs: -1, 5) -- (axis cs: 0.5, 5);
\draw[fill] (axis cs: 0.5, 5) circle [radius=2.0pt];

\draw[dashed] (axis cs: 1, -1) -- (axis cs: 1, 7);
\draw[dashed] (axis cs: -1, 7) -- (axis cs: 1, 7);
\draw[fill] (axis cs: 1, 7) circle [radius=2.0pt];

\addplot [samples=2, domain=0:1.4] {3+4*x};

\node[above right] (cs:1, cs:7) {$\mathbf{E}\left(Y|X_{i}\right)=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}X$};

\node[above right] (axis cs: 15, 25) {Distribution of \\$Y$ values \\given $X=x_3$};

\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Still Issues**

1. Text nodes are correctly placed.
2. Line passes through the means does not intersect y-axis.

Comment: You should use the `axis cs:` instead, I guess: `\draw (axis cs: 0, 0) -- (axis cs: 5, 16) -- (axis cs: 0, 16);`

Comment: Thenks @Qrrbrbirlbel for your comment, please see my edited question. Thanks

Comment: What happened there? `(cs:1, cs:7)`? Should probably read `(axis cs: 1, 7)`, too. That the line does not pass until the *y* axis is due the `enlarge x limits` style. You can however just give a smaller *x* value on the domain, say `domain:-1:1.4`. The plots are usually clipped.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I tried that too but did not work.

Comment: Ah, yes. You forgot `at`, i.e. `at (axis cs: 1,7)` and `at (axis cs: 15, 25)`. In your case, you just name the nodes. The placement defaults to `(0, 0)` in this case.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Good pick, it is my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coordinate system from TikZ is of no use when `pgfplots` does its works. It redefines the *x* and the *y* vectors to its own usage. You should use the `axis cs:` and the `rel axis cs:` coordinate system instead to refer to coordinates from the axes. (There are other `cs:`s like the `xticklabel cs:` used in your code and helpful (pseudo-)nodes that refer to the axes, the labels or the plot.)

I have added an `insert path` style for your dashed markers that takes two arguments: the *x* value and the *y* value. A black dot is automatically drawn at the `(<x>, <y>)` coordinate with the filled circular node. So that these touch the axes, I have used the `rel axis cs:` with which one can access coordinate `rel`atively to the axes. The lower-left corner is `(rel axis cs: 0, 0)`, the upper-right is `(rel axis cs: 1, 1)`.

I have used the same for your nodes with `(rel axis cs: 1, 0)` to refer to the lower-right corner. I’e just placed these description in the corner because I didn’t know where else to place them. There might as well be used in a legend (`pgfplots` can do this, too).

The `enlarge x limits` styles makes the axes a little bit longer than the values from the `domain` would suggest. This is also the reason why the straight line doesn’t touch the *y* axis. I have fixed this with a manual set `xmin=0` in the `axis` options and a `domain` that starts at `-1`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ % Define Normal Probability Function
  declare function={normal(\x,\m,\s) = 1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(\x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));},
  xy marker/.style 2 args={
    insert path={
      ({rel axis cs: 0,0}-|{axis cs: #1,0})
        |- node[shape=circle, fill, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+4pt]{}
      ({rel axis cs: 0,0}|-{axis cs: 0,#2})}}]

\begin{axis}[
    no markers, xmin=0, axis lines=left,
    samples=100,
    enlarge x limits=true,  enlarge y limits=true,
    xtick={0, 0.5, 1}, ytick={3, 5, 7},
    xticklabels={$X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$},
    yticklabels={$Y_1$, $Y_2$, $Y_3$},
    xlabel=$X$, xlabel style={at=(xticklabel cs:1), anchor=south},
    ylabel=$Y$, ylabel style={at=(yticklabel cs:1), rotate=-90, anchor=west},
  ]

\addplot[cyan!50!black, thick, domain=0:6] ({normal(x, 3, 1)+0.0},x);
\addplot[cyan!50!black, thick, domain=2:8] ({normal(x, 5, 1)+0.5},x);
\addplot[cyan!50!black, thick, domain=4:10] ({normal(x, 7, 1)+1},x);

\draw[dashed, xy marker/.list={{0}{3},{.5}{5},{1}{7}}];
\addplot [samples=2, domain=-1:1.4] {3+4*x};

\begin{scope}[nodes={align=center, fill=white, fill opacity=.7, text opacity=1}]
\node[rounded corners=+7pt, above left] (@)
    % rounded corners so that the node doesn't overlay the arrow tip form the x axes
  at (rel axis cs: 1, 0) {Distribution of \\$Y$ values \\given $X=x_3$};
\node[above left] at (@.north east) {$\mathbf{E}\left(Y|X_{i}\right)=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}X$};
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: What about 3D version?